# AngularJS: Swiper.js not showing background images

Tags: angularjs, swiper.js

I´m trying to integrate swiper.js in my angularJs web app displaying background images. The library is working but the images are not properly displayed. Please see this plunker that is working exactly like my app.

http://plnkr.co/edit/ISdEZn?p=preview

Below the most relevant part:

```
<!-- Slider main container -->
    <div class="swiper-container" swiper>
        <!-- Additional required wrapper -->
        <div class="swiper-wrapper">
            <!-- Slides -->
            <!--<div class="swiper-slide">Slide 1</div>-->
            <!--<div class="swiper-slide">Slide 2</div>-->
            <!--<div class="swiper-slide">Slide 3</div>-->

            <div class="swiper-slide" ng-repeat="boatPhoto in boatPhotos" is-loaded>                    
                    <div style="margin:auto; background-image: url('//s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/yanpy.dev/img/boats/13620/l/{{boatPhoto.name}}.{{boatPhoto.mime}}')">
                    </div>
              </div>                
        </div>
        <!-- If we need pagination -->
        <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>

        <!-- If we need navigation buttons -->
        <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
        <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>

        <!-- If we need scrollbar -->
        <div class="swiper-scrollbar"></div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set width and height of the div.

```
<div style="margin:auto;width:100%;height:100%; background-image: url('//s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/yanpy.dev/img/boats/13620/l/{{boatPhoto.name}}.{{boatPhoto.mime}}')">
     Hola
</div>
```

**[Updated plnkr demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/qUmRCFZDB3ZJiIbK4pXZ?p=preview)**